# Helper function Rails 3 fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view-helpers

I've done! very lucky, I was working on it for about three days, what rewrote the code at my show view like this:

```
<ul>
<%= @tags.each do |z| %>
    <% if z.name == @tag.name %>
        <li style="visibility:hidden"><%= id = z.tagable_id %></li>
        <p>User name:<strong> <%= find_user(id)%></strong></p>
        <li>Post content:<strong><%= post = find_post(id)%></strong></li>
    <% end %>
<% end%>

</ul>
```

The problem now is that below the information an wried code is show, this code is the list of all the tags that I have:

```
[#<Tag id: 1, name: "septiembre", tagable_id: 301, tagable_type: "Post", created_at:       "2012-09-25 23:43:02", updated_at: "2012-09-25 23:43:02">, #<Tag id: 2, name: "Septiembre", tagable_id: 302, tagable_type: "Post", created_at: "2012-09-26 15:40:54", updated_at: "2012-09-26 15:40:54">, #<Tag id: 3, name: "Octubre", tagable_id: 302, tagable_type: "Post", created_at: "2012-09-26 17:11:04", updated_at: "2012-09-26 17:11:04">, #<Tag id: 4, name: "septiembre", tagable_id: 302, tagable_type: "Post", created_at: "2012-09-26 18:45:54", updated_at: "2012-09-26 18:45:54">, #<Tag id: 5, name: "septiembre\r\n", tagable_id: 303, tagable_type: "Post", created_at: "2012-09-27 00:09:36", updated_at: "2012-09-27 00:09:36">, #<Tag id: 6, name: "septiembre", tagable_id: 304, tagable_type: "Post", created_at: "2012-09-27 00:10:26", updated_at: "2012-09-27 00:10:26">, #<Tag id: 7, name: "Octubre", tagable_id: 305, tagable_type: "Post", created_at: "2012-09-27 00:10:47", updated_at: "2012-09-27 00:10:47">]
```

What do you think??

Comment: your result is fully logic: you extract elements one by one then try to match each one with some of the initial collection. Obviously, one element will always match itself, so you get them all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `<%= @tags.each do |z| %>` to `<% @tags.each do |z| %>`. The = sign means render to the html so it shows the `@tags` variable.